# Giving row with one column all vertical space

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to have a row/column take up all space vertically. I managed to do this for col2 but have no idea what I need to get "col 1 content" to grow vertically. Can someone elaborate what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-container class="grow d-flex flex-column flex-nowrap ">
            <v-row >
                <v-col  class="grow pa-0">
                     <!--<v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3"> Subheader </v-card>-->
                     <v-container class="grow d-flex flex-column pa-0 flex-nowrap">
                    <v-row >
                        <v-col >
                            <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3"> Col 1 - head </v-card>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    <v-row class="grow">
                        <v-col >
                            <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3 "> Col 1 - content </v-card>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                    </v-container>
                </v-col>
                <v-col class="grow box" v-if="show">
                     <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3 fill-height"> Col 2 - panel </v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row class="shrink">
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-card elevation="2" class="pa-3"> row 2</v-card>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Try to get the v-card with "Col 1 - content " to fill the vertical space 

https://www.codeply.com/p/fAJy1lUuBg